# Build variants in Xamarin for Android

Tags: android, xamarin, android-gradle-plugin

We currently have an Android application that we would like to translate to Xamarin for Android.

Our app uses [build variants](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants) to create different [product flavors](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors).

However I cannot find any documentation explaining whether this is possible in Xamarin or what would be the workaround.

Does anybody have experience with this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Both of those concerns (product flavours and build variants) aren't really an "Android" thing, they are a software configuration issue that Gradle supports.

Although Xamarin.Android doesn't support Gradle, it is possible to create build variants as described in that link. Xamarin.Android allows you to choose the ABI's that you're targeting. With a bit of scripting you can create one APK per ABI (which you can then upload to Google Play).

Likewise, with the appropriate scripting, you could also support product flavours in a couple of different ways:

- Using compile time directives, i.e. `#if` statements
- Architect your app so that certain features are in certain assemblies that are omitted at compile time or a different for each flavour.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't understand exactly how ABI's can be compared to variants. How could I for instance change the package name and the package icon?

Comment: Not really, in the end we decided Xamarin was not the best option for the project.